# A nilpotency question on $C^{*}$ algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, operator-theory

What is  an example of a $C^{*}$  algebra $A$ with the property that: for  every nilpotent(Quasi nilpotent) $a$ and for  every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there is a  $b$  with $b^{n}=a$.

> To what extent such  algebras are  classified?

Comment: I suppose you aren't interested in commutative $A$'s?

Comment: @RobertIsrael As you said, in this  question we ignore the  commutative $C^{*}$  algebras, since there is  no nilpotent element other than $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is useful: If your $C^*$-algebra also has a non-zero nilpotent element, then it will have nilpotent elements of all orders, it is not (algebraically) of bounded index, so does not satisfy a polynomial identity.  $C^*$-algebras which *do* satisfy a polynomial identity are the subject of the following paper: B. E. Johnson. "Near inclusions for subhomogeneous $C^*$-algebras", Proc. London Math. Soc., 68:399–422, 1994.